# How to display EditText in a TextView after changing it to BigDecimal?

Tags: android, bigdecimal

I want to get a precise number from an EditText then change in to a BigDecimal and show it in another TextView.
Here's a part of my code:

```
BigDecimal rate_string = new BigDecimal(0);
EditText rate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.rate_edittext);
rate_string = (BigDecimal) rate.getText();
TextView test = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
test.setText(rate_string.toString());
```

But it doesn't work!
What should I do?
Thanks

Comment: How you want to convert a text to a BigDecimal with a cast?

Comment: I don't know! I think that's the problem. Do you know a way to convert a text to BigDecimal? @MarcoAcierno

Comment: I'm changing my code right now @MarcoAcierno

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
BigDecimal rate_string = new BigDecimal(0);
EditText rate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.rate_edittext);
rate_string = (BigDecimal) rate.getText();
TextView test = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
test.setText(rate_string.toString());
```

to

```
BigDecimal rate_string; // P.S here is useless the creation
EditText rate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.rate_edittext);
rate_string = new BigDecimal( rate.getText().toString() );
TextView test = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
test.setText(rate_string.toString());
```

You cannot convert a String to a `BigDeciaml` using a cast but `BigDecimal` have a constructor which takes the value as String.

P.S Make sure you pass a correct number to the constructor or it will throw a `NumberFormatException`!

Comment: String is a thing, BigDecimal is another. it's not like native types... you can do this type of cast only if the classes have some kind of relations between them (extend, interface etc.) online you can found some tutorials i can't say more in the comments. Ask a question if you want to know.